# Choose correct answers on eigen value:

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant, matrix-equations

A =

```
[0 0 L 0 1
 1 0 L 0 0
 0 1 L 0 0
 M M N N M
 0 0 L 1 0]
```

a) eigenvalue are purely real
b) 0 is the only eigenvalue
c) eigenvalues are n-th roots of unity Exp(2πi/n) for i = 0,1,...,n-1
d) none of these

What can be the easiest way to get answers in these type of questions?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What are $l,m,n$ are? another thing why do not evaluate the eigen values?

Comment: I have tried calculating |A - λI| and then putting it to zero to find lambda, as I know only this way of finding eigenvalues. It is a very tough way, I want to know if there is some smart way to do such questions

Comment: l, m, n are some unknown elements in the matrix

Comment: Perhaps show the expression that you found for $\det(A-\lambda I)$

Comment: Note that $L=1$, $M=0$, and $N=1$ makes $(1,1,1,1,1)$ an eigenvector with eigenvalue $\lambda=2$.

Comment: @MichaelBurr $-λ^5 + λ^4 L + λ^3 L + λ^2 L + λ L - λ^2 L M - 2 λ L M - 3 L M - λ^3 L N - λ^2 L N - λ L N - L N + λ^3 M + λ^2 M + λ M + λ^4 N + N$, [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B0%2C0%2Cx%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2Cx%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2Cx%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7By%2Cy%2Cz%2Cz%2Cy%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2Cx%2C1%2C0%7D%7D)

Comment: Your work already shows that $(B)$ and $(C)$ are not possible.  The constant term of the determinant is the product of the eigenvalues.  This constant term is $-3LM-LN+N$, which doesn't have to be $0$ (so $(B)$ isn't possible) and you can make it so that the constant term isn't norm $1$ (so $(C)$ isn't possible).  Now, by choosing different values for $L$, $M$, and $N$, perhaps you can get a complex eigenvalue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the best option is really to pick nice values for $N$, $M$, and $L$ and try to compute.  This matrix doesn't appear to have enough structure to answer this type of question quickly (although I might be missing something).

Sketch:

1.) Compute eigenvalues for $L=1$, $M=0$, and $N=1$.  This gets rid of two possibilities (note that the rows sum to $2$).

2.) Compute the eigenvalues for $L=0$, $M=0$, and $N=1$.  This gets rid of one more case (note that this choice eliminates most of the terms in the characteristic equation and Descartes' rule of signs can be applied to the polynomial to count the real roots).